# AngularJS : Add click listener without using ng-click (for dynamicaly added data from a Json API)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im creating a hybrid application using **Cordova**, **AngularJs** and **Ionic**. Im getting my data from **Wordpress** using a JSON API plugin.

Here is my single post view :

```
<ion-view view-title="Single View">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="card single-view" ng-show="show_post">
            <div class="title" ng-bind-html="data['post'].title"></div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img ng-src="{{data['post'].thumbnail_images['single-post-thumb'].url}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="content" ng-bind-html="data['post'].content"></div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Is there any way to add a click listener on every image that will be generated on my content div, so i can open a modal with a full size image when i click on it thumb ?

P.S: I dont use jquery, In **JQuery** it will be something like :

```
$('.content > a > img ').bind("click", function(e){
   //open my modal..
});
```

Comment: Your example jQuery wouldn't work either. Which elements here are static and which are generated? Either way, you should use a directive for this

Comment: A few things: (1) Do you use jQuery in this project? (2) Do you want Angular to *know* about the click (e.g. does Angular handle it? does it affect Angular's model in any way?)

Comment: the hole content is generated at the same time, but the problem is that i cant control the content of this div : <div class="content"..></div>, so it wont be possible to add the ng-click attribute on the img tags that will be inside that div

Comment: No i dont use jquery on my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution !

The data that i recieve from my Wordpress Api contains images inside links, its something like this : 
 `<a href=""><img src=".." /></a>`

So instead of directly putting my html content inside the ng-bind-html, i managed to do something like this :

1. I save my html content inside a variable then i use the replace function to replace all the **href** attributes with the **ng-click="showImage()" img-src=**

   $scope.data = items;
   var post_content =items['post'].content;
   $scope.content=$sce.trustAsHtml(post_content.replace(/href=/gm, 'ng-click="showImage()" img-src='));
2. I binded this html code using template attribute :

   `<div class="post-content" template="{{content}}"></div>`
3. I recompiled my html code using a directive like this :

   ```
   angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
   .controller(............)
   .directive( 'showData', function ( $compile ) {
     return {
       scope: true,
       link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
         var el;

         attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( tpl ) {
           if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) ) {
             el = $compile( tpl )( scope );
             element.html("");
             element.append( el );
           }
         });
       }
   ```

   };
   });

I just need to know how to check if the href contain an image or not.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a `directive` with a link function that will add the plugin and  decorate all your images with it. Something like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" image-modal />
```

and

```
app.directive('imageModal', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var options = {}; // settings.
      elem.modal(options); 
      // maybe add a elem.on('click', function(){}) for showing the modal
     }
  };
});
```

Comment: i dont know anything about **directives**, i will check about that and will tell u about the result thx

Comment: That's the correct way to add jquery plugins (and modify the dom) in your angular application.

Comment: But i dont think that its a good habbit to add a hole library to a project just for 1 instruction

Comment: Your not adding JQuery to angular since angular has a jquery lite version that he works with. Your creating a JQuery wrapper using a directive. This directive expands you "html vocabulary" and lets you add functionality on elements quickly.

Comment: I cant add custom directive to my img tags cuz i dont have control on my html content. it comes from a json server